# Validar y agregar el producto

Tags: python

Debo validar y agregar el producto si no existe y si existe, sumar a la existencia.

Agrego código Phyton

```
inventario[{
    "id": "019", 
    "nombre": "recogedores", 
    "marca": "la brujita", 
    "categoria": "aseo", 
    "fecha de ingreso": "14/03/2021",
    "fecha de caducidad": "25/04/2021",
    "existencias": 60,    
    "precio": 3500, 
    "presentacion": "und" 
    
},{
    "id": "020", 
    "nombre": "valdes", 
    "marca": "la brujita", 
    "categoria": "aseo", 
    "fecha de ingreso": "14/03/2021",
    "fecha de caducidad": "25/04/2021",
    "existencia": 55,   
    "precio": 4000, 
    "presentacion": "und" 
     
},{
    "id": "021", 
    "nombre": "alcancias", 
    "marca": "el marranito", 
    "categoria": "cacharreria", 
    "fecha de ingreso": "15/02/2021", 
    "fecha de caducidad": "25/04/2021", 
    "precio": 3500, 
    "presentacion": "und",
    "existencias": 50 
    
},{
    "id": "022", 
    "nombre": "materos", 
    "marca": "alfarero", 
    "categoria": "cacharreria", 
    "fecha de ingreso": "15/02/2021", 
    "fecha de caducidad":"25/04/2021", 
    "existencias": 50, 
    "precio": 5500, 
    "presentacion": "und" 
         
}]

producto = {}
id = input("ingrese el id del producto:")
nombre = input("ingrese el nombre del producto:")
marca = input("ingrese marca del producto:")
categoria = input("ingrese categoria del producto:")
fecha_de_ingreso = input("ingrese fecha de ingreso del productos:")
fecha_de_caducidad = input("ingrese fecha de caducidad del productos:")
existencias = input("ingrese existencia del productos:")
precio = input("ingrese precio del productos:")
presentacion = input("ingrese presentacion del productos:")


producto["id"] = id
producto["nombre"] = nombre
producto[" marca"] =  marca
producto["categoria"] = categoria
producto["fecha de ingreso"] = fecha_de_ingreso
producto["fecha de caducidad"] = fecha_de_caducidad
producto["existencias"] = existencias
producto["precio"] = precio
producto["presentacion"] = presentacion

def buscar_categoria(categoria):
  for i in range(0,len(inventario)-1):
   if categoria.upper()==inventario[i].upper():
     return i
  return -1

print(inventario)
```

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta sería ...?

Comment: como hago es que no se como  aplicar el ciclo

Answer (score 0):

Doy por supuesto que el `id` es un identificador único para cada artículo, ni hay un artículo con 2 'id' ni 2 artículos con la misma 'id'.

Creo una función que recibe el `id` y el `inventario` . Recorre la lista y  devuelve un diccionario vacío si no lo encuentra o un diccionario con los datos del producto con esa `id`.

```
def busca_id(codigo, almacen):
    """
    Returns diccionario encontrado o vacío
    """
    art_almacen = {}
    for articulo in almacen:
        if articulo['id'] == codigo:
            art_almacen = articulo.copy()
    return art_almacen
```

voy a cargarlo en un diccionario auxiliar `prod_aux` con el que se pueden hacer más comparaciones si hacen falta y las operaciones con las existencias.

```
prod_aux = busca_id( producto['id'], inventario )
if len( prod_aux ) == 0:
    inventario.append(producto) #  Devolvió el diccionario vacio así que añado los datos a la lista
 
else:
    #   Índice dentro de la lista inventario  en que está el producto
    indice = inventario.index( prod_aux )

    #   Sumo los artículos nuevos
    prod_aux['existencias'] += producto['existencias']  #  Sumo a las existencias del inventario.

    inventario[indice] = prod_aux.copy()
```

> En la pregunta al crear la lista `inventario` falta un símbolo '='